# How to retain position of scrollview?

Tags: android, button, webview, scrollview

How can i retain the position of a scrollview,?

When i click the button which is in the scrollview a webview opens (which is in a different activity) and then when we press the back button the scrollview starts from the top. But i want to retain the position of the scrollview how can i do it??

i tried to use this, but dint work.

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, 200);
```

in onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    scrollView.scrollTo(0, position);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way in your `OnResume()`

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, position);
         }
 });
```

Comment: @Saad Please notify me whether this helps you or not.

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot. it also works for fragments when called in `onViewCreated`.

Answer (score 1):

> You should memorise the value of ScrollView.ScrollPosition in a
>   process global variable in Activity_Pause and restore that value in
>   Activity_Resume.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution works but I have some visual bug using it. I can see the top of the ScrollView before scrolling to the desired postion.

I ended up using a OnPreDrawListener and it works very well.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, position);
        mView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        return true;
    }
});
```